# I'm trying to import a JSON file into MongoDB using Python. I keep getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'" error

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to import a JSON file into MongoDB using Python. I already have pymongo installed. I keep getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'" error.

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient('localhost')
db = client['posts_db']
collection_recent = db['recent']

with open('posts.json') as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)

# use collection_currency.insert(file_data) if pymongo version < 3.0
collection_currency.insert_one(file_data)  
client.close()
```

Comment: The error message means you didn't install pymongo. What did you do to install it?

Comment: @Taegyung How do I install it through cmd?

Comment: You said "I already have pymongo installed." How did you do it?

Comment: @Taegyung Well I did, but I thought I did it wrong or something. On cmd: python -m pip install pymongo. It says requirement already satisfied